# How to get time sum

Tags: php

I need to get time sum in normal format, im trying like this

```
$total_extra += $arr['extra'][$i]
echo $total_extra;
```

`['extra']` time format is example "10:30"

I getting only hours in sum without min example "20", but i need full sum format like in "hours:mins"

Comment: PHP doesn't add times and intervals like this. You need the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: I suggest converting your times to a base unit (e.g. seconds) and then adding those up instead.

Comment: @RK. $total_extra += $arr['extra'][$i] is in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to minutes (using explode() is what you need here), do the math, then convert it back to "hour:min".

```
$a = '10:30';
$b = '4:20';

$aExploded = explode(':', $a);
$bExploded = explode(':', $b);

$aMinutes = $aExploded[0]*60 + $aExploded[1];
$bMinutes = $bExploded[0]*60 + $bExploded[1];

$sum = $aMinutes + $bMinutes;

$sumString = floor($sum / 60).':'.($sum % 60);

echo $sumString;
```

Comment: or you could just use `DateInterval`

Comment: But if i have single variable time? i just need to use only $a variant? because $arr['extra'][$i] is in the for loop and i need sum from all times.

Comment: @SkySonny: I just gave you and example of solution. You need to use it in your own way... Use the $sum of minutes through all your loop cycles - this should work.